# Can't figure out why AngularJS doesn't read JSON from PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, json, mysqli

I've spent hours trying to figure this out and browsing the web, but I must be doing something wrong. Every time i load the page it's just blank. 
I'm trying to load the database from mysqli to angularjs.
The code is copied exactly from W3 exercises so I have no idea where the problem is.

dbaseread.php is in the same folder as the html.

PHP:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM members";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    $r = array();
    if( $result->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $r[] = $row;
    }
    }


    $res = json_encode($r);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $res;
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
    {{ x.name }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("dbaseread.php").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.records;
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try decoding the response before using it... i know ir sounds weird just try it... json_decode($response, true); I have been working with json files the last few days my JS refuses to read it unless i decode it first and use the true parameter

Comment: try `$scope.myData = response.data`. Doesn't look like any `records` property in the php. Inside the `then` can put `console.log(response.data)` then look in browser console at what is actually returned

Comment: @silverpenguin that is for decoding, not encoding

Comment: @charlietfl Oh, thank you so much, that fixed it! I can't believe it was such a silly mistake

Comment: For the future, this is exactly what the debugger is for. Open the scripts page of the inspector in chrome and but a break point inside that then function and you can see exactly what your working with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> try `$scope.myData = response.data`. Doesn't look like any `records`
>   property in the php. Inside the `then` can put
>   `console.log(response.data)` then look in browser console at what is
>   actually returned

– charlietfl

There indeed wasn't any 'records' property, so removing it fixed the issue.